# How can i keep the changes that i made using Modernizr even when i dont resize the page

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I'm building a responsive Website, and i'm using modernizr to improve the page. Modernizr is very new to me.

The problem is that I have to resize the page to see the changes that I made.

I would like to change the page in two ways, when someone resize (i already got that), and when the page is reloaded. Because if someone opens the page in a certain device, my changes could not work.

How can i do that?

```
    function checkMq() {
        if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 1168px)')) {

            if ($('.leftside').hasClass('active')) {
                $(".m-contact").css("visibility", "visible");
            } else {

            }


        }
        if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 1169px)')) {

            if ($('.leftside').hasClass('active')) {
                $(".m-contact").css("visibility", "hidden");
            } else {
                $(".m-contact").css("visibility", "visible");
            }


        }
    }


    $(function() {
        checkMq();

        $(window).resize(function() {
            checkMq();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could force resize at the end of the script using:

```
$(window).resize();
```

Or use a Timeout to set it after 200ms for example using:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $(window).resize();
}, 200);
```

This will force window to resize and If i have understood correctly changes will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You already calling the function **checkMq** on DOM ready event so it should work without any doubt. What made you think that it will not work?